# PHP: 3 time periods with different pricing

Tags: php, calculator

It's all about booking...

I've got 3 time periods:

> ```
> Period 3 from 01.01.2014 to 29.04.2014 - Price 3 (per day)
> Period 2 from 30.04.2014 to 14.06.2014 - Price 2 (per day)
> Period 1 from 15.06.2014 to 21.09.2014 - Price 1 (per day)
> Period 4 from 22.09.2014 to 29.04.2015 - Price 3 (per day)
> ```

I've already made a php calculation that calculates the booked days and pricing for each period. But I can't figure it out how to calculate between two periods.

For example:
Somebody books from `26.01.2014 to 25.04.2014 = 89 days * Price 1`

But it gets really hard when somebody books from period 3 to period 1 for... I tried to separate the calculations:

```
   if ($check_in >= '2013-04-30' && $check_out <= '2014-09-21')
     {
    //Days and price calcs here
    // contains Period 2 and Period 1
     }
```

But it doesn't work well...

Do you have any ideas how to make the whole calculation to work perfectly?

I missed something really important.

Here is the structure:

Period 1

```
if($numberDays == 1)
{
$price = $price1_period1
}

if($numberDays >= 2 && $numberDays <= 3)
{

$price = $price2_period1 * $numberDays;
}

if($numberDays >= 4 && $numberDays <= 6)
{
$price = $price3_period1 * $numberDays;
}

if($numberDays >= 7 && $numberDays <= 14)
{
$price = $price4_period1 * $numberDays;
}

if($numberDays >= 15 && $numberDays <= 29)
{

$price = $price5_period1 * $numberDays;
} 

if($numberDays >= 30)
{
$price = $price6_period1 * $numberDays;
}
```

It's the same for the other periods.
 Ex.: for period 2 the price for 6 days is $price3_period2.

Comment: What exactly does "But it doesn't work well..." mean? What does it do and what would you like it to do instead?

Comment: Thank you, but it didn't work for me. I missed something really important. Check out the question again, I've editted it. Everything works perfect when it comes ot check in and check out in particular period. But when someone check ins from Period 1 and check outs to period 2 (or 3) it returns nothing, because I cant join all the periods :(

Comment: Any other sugestions?

Answer (score 2):

You could generate a price for each day. Then loop from start date to end date and sum the dayprice to get the total price:

```
<?php
$oneDay = 24*3600;

$configs = array(
    array(
        'startTime' => strtotime('2014-01-01'),
        'endTime' => strtotime('2014-04-29'),
        'price' => 10
    ),
    array(
        'startTime' => strtotime('2014-04-30'),
        'endTime' => strtotime('2014-06-14'),
        'price' => 20
    ),
    array(
        'startTime' => strtotime('2014-06-15'),
        'endTime' => strtotime('2014-09-21'),
        'price' => 30
    ),
    array(
        'startTime' => strtotime('2014-09-22'),
        'endTime' => strtotime('2015-04-29'),
        'price' => 40
    ),
);

$prices = array();
foreach ($configs as $config)
{
    $time1 = $config['startTime'];
    $time2 = $config['endTime'];
    $price = $config['price'];

    while ($time1 <= $time2)
    {
        $prices[date('Y-m-d', $time1)] = $price;
        $time1 += $oneDay;
    }
}

/**
 * @param $checkIn in format YYYY-mm-dd
 * @param $checkOut in format YYYY-mm-dd
 */
function getTotalPrice($checkIn, $checkOut, $prices)
{
    $time1 = strtotime($checkIn);
    $time2 = strtotime($checkOut);

    $price = 0;
    while ($time1 <= $time2)
    {
        $time1 += 24 * 3600;
        $price += $prices[date('Y-m-d', $time1)];
    }

    return $price;
}

echo getTotalPrice('2014-01-04', '2014-01-09', $prices);
```

Comment: Thank you, but it didn't work for me. I missed something really important. Check out the question again, I've editted it.

Answer (score 1):

First things first, I assume `$check_in` and `$check_out` are strings that you get from some form, then you are comparing them with another string, any of them are dates.

What you can do is convert both `$check_in` and `$check_out` to Datetime and then do the comparison, example:

```
// Check In Date
$check_in_date = new Datetime($check_in);
$date_compare_in = new Datetime('2013-04-30');

$diff_in = $check_in_date->diff($date_compare_in);

// Check Out Date
$check_out_date = new Datetime($check_out);
$date_compare_out = new Datetime('2014-09-21');

$diff_out = $check_out_date->diff($date_compare_out);
```

Now `$diff_in` is a DateInterval object that you can check for the quantity of days, example, if the hours are greater than 0, the $check_in was later than the compare date, if is less than 0 the $check_in was before.

```
if($diff_in->h >= 0 and $diff_out->h <= 0){
// We are within this date range.
}
```

a DateInterval Object has the following structure:

```
DateInterval Object
(
    [y] => 0
    [m] => 0
    [d] => 0
    [h] => 0
    [i] => 0
    [s] => 0
    [invert] => 0
    [days] => 0
)
```

Comment: Thank you, but it didn't work for me. I missed something really important. Check out the question again, I've editted it. Everything works perfect when it comes ot check in and check out in particular period. But when someone check ins from Period 1 and check outs to period 2 (or 3) it returns nothing, because I cant join all the periods :(